# How do I scroll d3 elements while keeping a portion of the svg in a fixed position?

Tags: css, html, d3.js

I am trying to understand how I can keep a certain part of a d3 visualization from scrolling while the rest of the visualization scrolls within the containing div.
A simple example of what I am trying to do is in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/51qs8q94/ .

HTML/JS

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="viz" class="content"></div>            
        </div>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var svg = d3.select("#viz")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 300)
                    .attr("height", 300);
            svg.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 40)
                    .attr("y", 10)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .text("LABEL");
            svg.append("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "green")
                    .style("fill", "green")
                    .attr("x", 50)
                    .attr("y", 25)
                    .attr("width", 25)
                    .attr("height", 25);
            svg.append("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "yellow")
                    .style("fill", "yellow")
                    .attr("x", 50)
                    .attr("y", 50)
                    .attr("width", 25)
                    .attr("height", 25);
            svg.append("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "green")
                    .style("fill", "green")
                    .attr("x", 50)
                    .attr("y", 75)
                    .attr("width", 25)
                    .attr("height", 25);
            svg.append("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "yellow")
                    .style("fill", "yellow")
                    .attr("x", 50)
                    .attr("y", 100)
                    .attr("width", 25)
                    .attr("height", 25);
            svg.append("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "green")
                    .style("fill", "green")
                    .attr("x", 50)
                    .attr("y", 125)
                    .attr("width", 25)
                    .attr("height", 25);
            svg.append("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "yellow")
                    .style("fill", "yellow")
                    .attr("x", 50)
                    .attr("y", 150)
                    .attr("width", 25)
                    .attr("height", 25);
            svg.append("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "green")
                    .style("fill", "green")
                    .attr("x", 50)
                    .attr("y", 175)
                    .attr("width", 25)
                    .attr("height", 25);
            svg.append("rect")
                    .style("stroke", "yellow")
                    .style("fill", "yellow")
                    .attr("x", 50)
                    .attr("y", 200)
                    .attr("width", 25)
                    .attr("height", 25);
        </script>        
    </body>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    float:left;
    height: 250px;
    width:250px; 
    padding:3px; 
    background:#FFA500;
}
.content{
    height:224px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

What I want is LABEL to stay visible at the top and for the D3 rects to scroll up and down beneath it. Is this possible? If so, how? Is it a CSS matter? SVG issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the svg text node as the last element to the svg element, so it will render on top of all the other elements. Then you can listen to the `scroll` event on your content div and adjust the `y` attribute of the text node.

Here is an example.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('viz');

var svg = d3.select("#viz")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 300)
.attr("height", 300);
svg.append("rect")
  .style("stroke", "green")
  .style("fill", "green")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 25)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
svg.append("rect")
  .style("stroke", "yellow")
  .style("fill", "yellow")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
svg.append("rect")
  .style("stroke", "green")
  .style("fill", "green")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 75)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
svg.append("rect")
  .style("stroke", "yellow")
  .style("fill", "yellow")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
svg.append("rect")
  .style("stroke", "green")
  .style("fill", "green")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 125)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
svg.append("rect")
  .style("stroke", "yellow")
  .style("fill", "yellow")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 150)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
svg.append("rect")
  .style("stroke", "green")
  .style("fill", "green")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 175)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
svg.append("rect")
  .style("stroke", "yellow")
  .style("fill", "yellow")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 200)
  .attr("width", 25)
  .attr("height", 25);
var label = svg.append("text")
.attr("x", 40)
.attr("y", 10)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text("LABEL");

content.addEventListener('scroll', function(evt) {
  label.node().setAttribute('y', 10 + this.scrollTop);
}, false)
```

```css
.container{
  float:left;
  height: 250px;
  width:250px; 
  padding:3px; 
  background:#FFA500;
}
.content{
  height:224px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="viz" class="content"></div>            
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! If anyone is curious to see it in action here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y2vd47qx/.